# Long run profit example

Tags: microeconomics

Can $C(q) = 2q^2$ be the long-run cost in a perfectly competitive market? It appears that if $p$ is the long-run price, then $p = MC = 4q$ and profit turns out to be $\pi(q) = 0.125p^2 > 0$. In fact, the quantity is fixed while in a competitive market, any quantity should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue with the cost function.

$p$ only equals $MC$ at the equilibrium and not for every quantity, as you have written. For example, if I produce $q=3$, the price will not be $12$.

To find the equilibrium price and quantity you should specify a demand function, so that you can find the point $(p,q)$ at which $MR=MC$.

Comment: Oh right! I see the details now. I assumed $p$ but I have to ensure that $p$ is determined wrt the demand function. So while we assume it an exogenous variable, to calculate the market price, we have to consider it in terms of $D(p)$. Once the market price is determined, then everything I wrote works (including treating $p$ as a constant). Is that correct?